# List mapped network drives from the command line to text file

Tags: windows, networking, command-line

Is there a command that can be used from the command line to output a list of the mapped network drives on the local system and their location on the network to a text file?

This will only be used on Windows-based systems running Windows XP.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`net use > mapped_drives.txt` should dump a list of mapped drives to the text file `mapped_drives.txt`

[image]

*Although I tested this on Windows 7, [Microsoft says](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) `net use` will work on Windows XP*

Comment: @MaterialEdge : Welcome!

Comment: I can confirm that it works on Windows XP.

Comment: Where is the location of the txt file?

Comment: @GeorgeLaed it will be in the same location as where you ran the command from

Comment: Note, under Windows 8 and above, this will not work in an elevated (run as administrator) command prompt because it's in a different security context. Open a "normal" command prompt to execute the command.

Comment: "net use" works in Win10 with normal permissions (blank list if you run the command window with admin permissions).

Answer (score 18):

`NET USE` was only displaying the mapped drives for my current user and current connection. After some more googling, I got [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/65eb8a2f-988f-40a7-b6ff-616a050c8efc/list-all-mapped-drives-for-all-users-that-have-logged-into-a-computer?forum=ITCG):

> The drive mapping info is stored in the Registry, look in
>   HKEY_USERS\USER\Network

So I did a `reg query HKEY_USERS` to list the users (which were some windows codes), then I queried all of them individually, for example:

```
reg query HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4205028929-649740040-1951280400-500\Network /s
```

If you query all of them, then you get all the mappings for all users.

Answer (score 6):

Save the following as a .vbs file and run it.  It'll create a MappedDrives.txt in the folder the vbs file is run from.  You can replace the strComptuer with another computer's name and get the list off of a remote computer as well.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(".\MappedDrives.txt")

Set colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4")

For Each objDrive in colDrives
    objOutFile.WriteLine(objDrive.DeviceID & " (" & _
      objDrive.ProviderName & ")")
Next

objOutFile.Close
```

Comment: Woah.  This is bad ass.  No idea it was possible (1) to write a query for drives, and (2) to do it remotely.  Awesome post.

Answer (score 3):

The following cmd (run as Administrator) will show all drive maps for all users (pulling the info from the registry)

`for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %i in ('reg query HKEY_USERS /f S* /k /v ^| findstr /v /c:"End of search"')do @echo. &  @( reg query "%i\Volatile Environment" /s /f USERNAME /v 2>NUL & @reg query %i\Network /f RemotePath /s 2>NUL )| findstr /r /v /c:"End of search"  /c:"^$" /c:"Volatile"`