# How can I find the IP address of a mapped Network drive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, nas, network-drive

How can I find the IP address of a mapped Network drive in Windows 10?

Comment: As I explained in the [Stack Overflow version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152005/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-of-a-mapped-network-drive-in-windows-10), you may want to include some more detail in your question.

Comment: You may think that, I couldn't possibly comment. As someone who doesn't know much in this field, finding the right words / terms to use isn't easy. That's what asking questions is all about.

Comment: If it's a path that starts with `\\ ` apparently those are called UNC paths... which aren't the same thing as a mapped network drive. I could for example map `\\someServer\directory\goodies` to be drive `G:\ ` on my local machine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Open CMD**

example Press **Windows Key** and **R**

type ping then the drive name example below

C:\Users\User>**ping htestrna01**

Pinging htestrna01.ad.com [11.30.137.214] with 32 bytes of data:

```
Reply from **11.30.137.214**: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 11.30.137.214: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 11.30.137.214: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 11.30.137.214: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Ping statistics for 11.30.137.214:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

**Then you will get the ip.**

Comment: That gives you the IP for a machine, but the question is how to get an IP from a mapped network drive.

Comment: The IP is of the network drive if it is connected to the machine.

Comment: Given a network drive `N:`, you cannot do `ping N:`.

Comment: I know that. That is how we have them setup at my job facilty we have the drive letter and the drive name which is the shared network drive.

Comment: You're missing the step for going from the mapped network drive to the host that the share is on.

Comment: Hi guys, this has answered it thanks. The mapped drive is a machine in its own right. I tried a lot of pinging in command prompt, but I'd been entering ping //nas-name or ping /nas-name etc. Now I see that you enter the name without any slashes, and it worked.

Answer (score 64):

Your question is two-pronged. A network share has no IP address, but the host that shares it has.

First, you want to resolve a drive letter to an UNC path, second you want to resolve the IP address of the host of that UNC path.

There are multiple ways to do this. See [How do I find where a network drive is mapped to in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/384692/how-do-i-find-where-a-network-drive-is-mapped-to-in-windows-7) and [List mapped network drives from the command line to text file](https://superuser.com/questions/135752/list-mapped-network-drives-from-the-command-line-to-text-file).

One way that's shown there: if you type `net use` in the command prompt, you'll get output like this:

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Z:        \\some-host\some-share
```

Now you see the drive (under "Local") and the UNC path (under "Remote"). The hostname of the UNC path is the part between the first two backslashes and the backslash after that (`some-host` in `\\some-host\`).

Then you can simply type `nslookup some-host` to find the IP address of that host:

```
C:\>nslookup some-host
Server:  your-dns
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    some-host
Address:  192.168.1.42
```

The IP you're looking for in this case is `192.168.1.42`.

Comment: Im connected, and I can do nslookup but when I do ping it says  DNS request timed out, server unknown !

Comment: Wait a sec. This is the correct answer.

Comment: This is the only correct answer here, as of 2022.

Comment: yeah, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click View network connections.

Select an active network connection, and then, in the toolbar, click View status of this connection. (You might need to click the chevron Picture of the chevron icon to find this command.)
Click Details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a NAS mapped onto my machine. When I go to View Network Connections, the only connection there is the Local Area Connection one, no mention of the network drive.

Comment: @AdamB, you are confusing physical connections with logical connections. your "Local Area Connection" is your physical network adapter, so all logical connections use it to communicate over the network. Logical connections, like those to a website or a network share or any other service are visible to you using commands like netstat, nbtstat, etc. If you want a gui tool to inspect connections, use Sysinternals TCPView.

Comment: Alas, this is an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Map network drive" in "Computer" and select the "Drive" from scroll down menu. It will show IP of the Drive automatically.